# Custom image for button in jQueryMobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

[image]

Button name "My Won " is not getting positioned below the image and a grey circle is coming with the image (Grey circle in right )
Style applied is

```
.ui-icon-myapp-depression{
            background: url("../images/depression.png") no-repeat;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
        }
```

HTML5 content is

```
<a href="#" id="btnDepression" data-role="button" data-icon="myapp-depression"
                  data-iconpos="right"
                    data-url="#" rel="external" >
                   My Won</a>
```

Comment: Tried with data-iconpos="bottom" as well

Answer (score 0):

Icons are displayed as background image of :after pseudo elements. Target the pseudo element to set a custom icon.
Try this:

```
.ui-icon-myapp-depression:after {
    background-image: url("../images/depression.png") no-repeat;
}
/* Fallback */
.ui-nosvg .ui-icon-myicon:after {
    background-image: url("iconimg.png");
}
```

for more information:
[Jquery mobile demos - icons](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/icons/)